# Magento 2 Cronjob plesk

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I've tried to add the cronjobs for Magento 2 with the Plesk panel. But it doesn't work. Have anyone experience or a solution?

PS.: Magento 1 was a little easier, only run the `cron.php` and it works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sv3n - Just to let you Stack guys know - this question saved my day, so I believe that marking it is as "off-topic" and suggesting to remove it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I set up my cronjobs:
h[image: Cronjobs overview]

[image: Cronjobs details]

You can view the error messages in /var/log/update.log
In my case I got the message:
"setup-cron.ERROR: Your current PHP memory limit is 128M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more."

Although my PHP memory limit was set to 3G, I also had to change the PHP Handler (Tools and Settings => Handler). Choose the right handler, search for "memory_limit" in php.ini and set it to a higher value (in my case 3G)